# let X is a normed vector space. if $ D \subseteq X$ is a balanced set $ D^0 \cup \{0\}$is a balanced set.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I tried to prove that:

"Let $X$ be a normed vector space. If $D \subseteq X$ is a balanced set then $D^0 \cup \{0\}$ is a balanced set."

$D^0$ is the interior of $D$.

I tried to prove it like this:

Let $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ and $ |\lambda| \le 1 $. If $x= 0$ or  $ \lambda=0 $ the result is obvious. Let $ x\in D^0$ and let $ \lambda \neq 0 $. Since $D$ is balanced, $ \lambda x \in D$. And, since $ x\in D^0 \Rightarrow \exists \epsilon >0 : B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq D$.

But, I don't know how I can use them for this proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq D$, $B(\lambda x, |\lambda|\epsilon) = \lambda B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq D$. As $\lambda \neq 0$, this implies $\lambda x \in D^0$.

Comment: thank you very much